# How to read file in Rails style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have some data stored as an XML file. I put it into a directory I've created, `app/data/myxml.xml`.

Now I want to parse it using Nokogiri. To locate the file I am referencing an absolute path:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("/home/me/webA/myrailsproject/app/data/myxml.xml"))
```

The absolute path definitely make the code ugly. Is there a shorter, cleaner way to reference the file? Such as:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("myxml"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current directory in a Rails is the application root, so you could just do

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("data/myxml.xml"))
```

Or if you want to be sure,  you can use the RAILS_ROOT constant -

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("#{RAILS_ROOT}/data/myxml.xml"))
```

Comment: both don't work for me, but the second one helped me find that "#{Rails.root}/app/data/myxml.xml" works good. did you try the first one? I expect that one should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Anar The real question, is did _you_ try it? ;) You might also want to consider using File.join to concatenate file paths, and looking at `File.expand_path` in the [rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html).

Comment: Updated, That's weird - I make it works on "app/data/myxml.xml" instead of "data/myxml.xml"

Comment: @lain, Yes I have tried, seems like "app/data/myxml.xml" works for me